# Why is typeof Not a Method?

Tags: javascript

Out of curiosity, what is the reasoning behind typeof not being a regular method or function, and instead putting it in front of the variable or data.

They do this:
`var something = typeof somethingElse;`

Rather than:
`var something = somethingElse.typeof();`

And also, what is the correct terminology for referring to the typeof and var keywords? Are they operators?

Comment: Yes, typeof is a unary operator.

Comment: Gotta admit, the first form is nicer to look at.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `typeof` is a unary operator, like `+`, `-`, `~`, `!` and `void`. `var`, on the other hand, is part of a variable declaration statement, and there is no fancy name for it.

I'm guessing the reason it wasn't made a method is twofold:

1. You can use it on `null` and `undefined`.
2. You can use it on undeclared variables without error.

If it were a regular method, neither of those would work, and adding special exceptions for particular method-looking things is messy.

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla docs refer to typeof as an operator. According to their [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the
>   unevaluated operand.

Note that it's not even really important what they call it, it is what the ECMA specs call it.

According to Mozilla's docs, the type of operator is defined in JavaScript 1.1 and ECMA Version: ECMA-262 (and ECMA-357 for E4X objects)

In case you are interested, the [ECMA 262 specs for version 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf) (warning - pdf link) go over the typeof operator in section 11.4.3 on page 71.

Comment: I don't understand how its supposed to not evaluate its argument. `typeof console.log('12')` prints a value just fine.

Comment: @missingro: MDN seems to be wrong; the specs state "Let `val` be the result of evaluating `UnaryExpression`" as the first step to execute. I *guess* MDN means you can apply it on undeclared variables without getting a `ReferenceError`.